# How to delete an entire data frame in Spark(SCALA)?

Tags: scala

There are functions to delete columns and rows in Spark(SCALA) but couldn't find any function to delete an entire data frame.Is there a way to delete a data frame in Spark(SCALA)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about which functions you are referring to delete columns from DFs. **Spark Dataframes are immutable in nature as like RDDs**. According to my understanding , its not possible. Only way to exaust an DF is garbage collection.

[Little more info on DataFrame](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/08/12/from-pandas-to-apache-sparks-dataframe.html)

Comment: def
drop(col: Column): DataFrame
Returns a new DataFrame with a column dropped. This version of drop accepts a Column rather than a name. This is a no-op if the DataFrame doesn't have a column with an equivalent expression.

Comment: Yeah, I agree we cannot delete or drop a column but we could create another data frame without the column that we want to remove. Following is the function I am referring to:                                                                         
def drop(col: Column): DataFrame
Returns a new DataFrame with a column dropped. This version of drop accepts a Column rather than a name. This is a no-op if the DataFrame doesn't have a column with an equivalent expression.

Comment: if you see, DF is not letting you to drop columns from your source DF but it returns a new DF. Even after your drop operation, u still can access those columns of your source DF. boz DF are immutable in nature.

Comment: @Akshay yeah you are at there.  but ur question does not sounds what you actually looking for. pls update your question